# Jquery animate() on multiple divs at the same time

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm trying to animate 15 divs out of my window.
I first animate these divs into the screen using the following code:

```
$('.title2').bind('click',function(){

    $('#i1 div').delay( 0 ).animate({left : 200,    top :210}, {duration: 'slow',easing: 'easeOutBack'});
    $('#i2 div').delay(100).animate({left : 250,    top :350}, {duration: 'slow',easing: 'easeOutBack'});
    $('#i3 div').delay(200).animate({left : 550,    top :200}, {duration: 'slow',easing: 'easeOutBack'});
    $('#i4 div').delay(400).animate({left : 450,    top :70},  {duration: 'slow',easing: 'easeOutBack'});
    $('#i5 div').delay(100).animate({left : 595,    top :60}, {duration: 'slow',easing: 'easeOutBack'});
    $('#i6 div').delay(900).animate({left : 580,    top :410}, {duration: 'slow',easing: 'easeOutBack'});
    $('#i7 div').delay(500).animate({left : 1020,   top :230}, {duration: 'slow',easing: 'easeOutBack'});
    $('#i8 div').delay(600).animate({left : 530,    top :550}, {duration: 'slow',easing: 'easeOutBack'});
    $('#ix div').delay(700).animate({left : 875,    top :270}, {duration: 'slow',easing: 'easeOutBack'});
    $('#v1 div').delay(100).animate({left : 350,    top :200}, {duration: 'slow',easing: 'easeOutBack'});
    $('#v2 div').delay( 0 ).animate({left : 380,    top :395}, {duration: 'slow',easing: 'easeOutBack'});
    $('#v3 div').delay(200).animate({left : 700,    top :150}, {duration: 'slow',easing: 'easeOutBack'});
    $('#v4 div').delay(800).animate({left : 880,    top :70}, {duration: 'slow',easing: 'easeOutBack'});
    $('#t1 div').delay(200).animate({left : 525,    top :335}, {duration: 'slow',easing: 'easeOutBack'});
    $('#t2 div').delay(400).animate({left : 998,    top :370}, {duration: 'slow',easing: 'easeOutBack'});
});
```

Now when i try to remove all these divs using a click for instance they only move within the y-axis.

This is the code for the return animation:

```
$('.title1').bind('click',function(){
        var alles = $('#i1 div,#i2 div,#i3 div,#i4 div,#i5 div,#i6 div,#i7 div,#i8 div,#ix div,#v1 div,#v2 div,#v3 div,#v4 div,#t1 div,#t2 div')
        alles.animate({right:0, top:200});
    });
```

Hope you guys can help.

Comment: Without more context it would be hard to know the reason. What is 'right' with regards to alles?

Comment: It's supposed to move alle the divs to the right. I only see them moving to top :200. Left however does work.. Any ideas?

Comment: @frenchie there is a 'right' property.

Comment: CSS does have a 'right' property @frenchie - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/right

Comment: All the divs are positioned using right. I did not use left to position them.

Comment: If they are positioned via 'right' then the opening animation should not work, as it uses 'left'

Comment: Where is 'right' in relation to the elements once you have animated them? Can you setup a fiddle or some other demo so that we can examine more closely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. I believe the problem you are having is that you are animating with left and then right, so the old left position overrides. You should animate by one or the other but not both. Here I am using the width of the offsetParent to provide the offscreen positioning for left. Also `bind` is deprecated, use `on` instead.

```
$('.title1').on('click',function(){
        $('#i1 div,#i2 div,#i3 div,#i4 div,#i5 div,#i6 div,#i7 div,#i8 div,#ix div,#v1 div,#v2 div,#v3 div,#v4 div,#t1 div,#t2 div').each(function(){
              var that = $(this),
                  WW   = that.offsetParent().width();                  
              that.animate({left:WW, top:200});
        });

});
```

---

```
$('#i1 div,#i2 div,#i3 div,#i4 div,#i5 div,#i6 div,#i7 div,#i8 div,#ix div,#v1 div,#v2 div,#v3 div,#v4 div,#t1 div,#t2 div').each(function(){
     var that = $(this);
     that.data('origin',[that.css('left'),that.css('top')]);
});

$('.title1').on('click',function(){
        $('#i1 div,#i2 div,#i3 div,#i4 div,#i5 div,#i6 div,#i7 div,#i8 div,#ix div,#v1 div,#v2 div,#v3 div,#v4 div,#t1 div,#t2 div').each(function(){
              var that = $(this),
                  origin = that.data('origin');                  
              that.animate({left:origin[0], top:origin[1]});
        });

});
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for your efforts. What was causing the problem in the end?

Comment: animating by left, and then animating by right. If you use both properties the browser will ignore one, because they can contradict.

Comment: Okay, i understand, is it also posible to return all divs to their original position( where they were before the animation)?

Comment: Yes. But you will have to record that data before moving them, so you can use that record to move them back.

Comment: Any tips for this? Maybe using a variable to store the X and Y values?

Comment: There are a bunch of ways. You could use an array, and html5 data-attribute, or jQuerie's `.data` function

Comment: I have no idea how to start. The divs that I use are hidden by default ( using a -margin). All of them are connected to timecodes so they show up at certain times. This works. When I click .title2 they all move into window to act like an overview. Now I would like them to go back to where they were. (hidden). I would like to be able to use these divs after they animate out.

Comment: Hope this clears things up. https://dl.dropbox.com/u/65815739/Case_Website/index.html Clicking on overview in the menu shows the divs. clicking on the orange square hides them. Still, the divs don't show up at the specified times when i continue the video.

Comment: That is a video sync issue, not a jquery animate issue. Check out popcorn.js for help with that one.

Comment: How do you mean sync issue? I'm not in a position to build the website around a whole new framework. I understand that would be best but I simply don't have the time.

Comment: "Still, the divs don't show up at the specified times when i continue the video." you are talking about a sync between the state of the video and your jquery animation. Its a whole other challenge.

Comment: No the sync works fine, however when the divs are moved once ,they dont animate anymore. So it's not the sync that's wrong.